# "sensors" showing temps like 127°C

Tags: radeon, temperature, sensors

When I run "sensors" from terminal one of the readings is really really high:

```
radeon-pci-0200
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:       +127.5°C
```

Obviously it's for the Graphics card but I doubt it's so hot. Could it be it's misconfigured?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out that this occurs when you have two graphic cards (integrated and discrete) and discrete is turned off (usually with *echo OFF > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch* at boot time).

If you [power on your discrete card](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HybridGraphics), the temperature readings become normal.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for this i was struggling mounths to find a solution

My Pc was shutting off every time it was so hot , and i was thinking it was the CPU fan not working well
But after installing lm-sensors i found :

```
ucefkh@01Tek:~$ sensors
atk0110-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
Vcore Voltage:      +1.26 V  (min =  +0.85 V, max =  +1.60 V)
 +3.3 Voltage:      +3.23 V  (min =  +2.97 V, max =  +3.63 V)
 +5 Voltage:        +5.02 V  (min =  +4.50 V, max =  +5.50 V)
 +12 Voltage:      +12.09 V  (min = +10.20 V, max = +13.80 V)
CPU FAN Speed:     675000 RPM  (min =  600 RPM)
CHASSIS FAN Speed: 2934 RPM  (min =  800 RPM)
CPU Temperature:    +20.0°C  (high = +60.0°C, crit = +95.0°C)

radeon-pci-0400
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:        +56.0°C  

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0:       +38.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:       +39.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
```

Now i just applied the propriety driver and i think it is working well !

Comment: Nice to hear that!